# java regular expression of block,not single line

Tags: java, regex

I like empire and I am modified AI.But when I test I find I lost a end like this "#end-if".
AI script is like this :

```
    (defconst gl-current-age 1)  
    (defconst TSA 2)
......<br/>
    #load-if-not-defined TURKISH-CIV<br/>
        (defrule<br/>
        (goal gl-fixed-eco-balancing NO)<br/>
        (up-compare-goal gl-current-age >= gv-feudal-up)<br/>
        (building-type-count barracks > 0)<br/>
        (or    (players-unit-type-count focus-player knight-line > 6)<br/>
               (players-unit-type-count focus-player boyar > 5))<br/>
        (unit-type-count-total spearman-line < 20)<br/>
        (timer-triggered 3)
        (game-time < 2700)                                          ;these are conditions<br/>
    =><br/>
        (up-modify-goal gl-food-gp-points c:+ 10)<br/>
        (up-modify-goal gl-wood-gp-points c:+ 8)                     ;these are actions<br/>
    )<br/>
    #else<br/>
        (defrule<br/>
        (goal gl-fixed-eco-balancing NO)<br/>
        (up-compare-goal gl-current-age >= gv-feudal-up)<br/>
        (building-type-count stable > 0)<br/>
        (or    (players-unit-type-count focus-player knight-line > 6)<br/>
               (players-unit-type-count focus-player boyar > 5))<br/>
        (unit-type-count-total camel-line < 8)<br/>
        (timer-triggered 3)<br/>
        (game-time < 2700)<br/>
    =><br/>
        (up-modify-goal gl-food-gp-points c:+ 10)<br/>
        (up-modify-goal gl-gold-gp-points c:+ 8)<br/>
    )<br/>
    #end-if                                           ;it is just a trigger<br/>
```

......

I have located the "#load..."which lacks ending but it makes no sense,because it is cross-module:that is problem.At last I decided to delete "(defrule"` and his")" in pairs also its contents and leave main frame,then I can compare the modified one and original one and find out the place .

So regular expression comes to my mind but I cannot continue.I am a newbie in programming and I only learn scanner ,how can java find the string(more than one line )when it reads only a single line? Also I am not sure of my expression "(defrule .* =>.*)\n)".

Thanks a lot.

1 This is an AI script which contains thirty thousands lines but I lose an ending , and I cannot find it because  there  is a function cross-module(not written by me).So I want to use java to find it out .

Problem 1 : How can java find the matched blocks while he only reads one line?

Problem 2:Is the regular expression  "(defrule .* =>.*)\n)" correct? (You see,the blocks begins with "(defrule"   and end  with ")"、'\n' and another ")" )

Comment: Please format your question better. And this is not Java.

Comment: Could you just show what you want to match from the input given?

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes,it's not java,just want to use java to solve it.

Comment: @Bohemian You see,the blocks I want to delete begin with "(defrule" and ends with ")"which leads a '/n'and ')',so I use these symbols as character to match the block.

Answer (score 0):

The regex that matches your target is:

```
(?ms)\(defrule.*?^\s*\)
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/r6LLhwGWqj).

To remove these targets from the input using java:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?ms)\\(defrule.*?^\\s*\\)", "");
```

Key points of the regex:

- `m` is the *multiline* flag, which lets ^ and $ match start and end of lines within the input
- `s` flag is the *dotall* flag, which lets a dot match newlines
- the expression `.*?` is a *reluctant* quantifier, which won't skip past the end of one section to match the end of a following section